# android- Search Result not display but already execute SELECT CRUD Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, crud, searchview

[Here is the UI after input keyword](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJeQG.png)

[image]

Hello, I am new to Android, I have read many tutorials, but they make database manual from the code. I want to make a search feature in the apps, retrieving data from sqlite database.

I use MainDIY for searching activity.

MainDIY.java

```
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import timber.log.Timber;


public class MainDIY extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemClickListener, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, SearchView.OnCloseListener{
    public static final String  KEY_ID      = "_id";

    private static final int    INSERT_ID   = Menu.FIRST;

    private DBAdapter           db;

    FloatingActionButton fab;
    ListView listview;
    private MyAdapter defaultAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> daftarData;
    //private ArrayList<String> arraylist=new ArrayList<String>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_diy);
        Timber.d("line 37, content activity_diy");
        db = new DBAdapter(this);
        db.open();



        //populate list
        /**
         daftarData = new ArrayList<String>();
         nameList.add("Apples");
         nameList.add("Oranges");
         nameList.add("Grapes");
         nameList.add("Pineapples");
         nameList.add("Mangoes");
         nameList.add("Watermelons");
         nameList.add("Strawberries");
         nameList.add("Bananas");
         nameList.add("Apricots");
         nameList.add("Olives");
         nameList.add("Peaches");
         nameList.add("Jackfruits");

         for (int i = 0; i < 6
         ; i++) {
         daftarData.add("Diana" + i);
         }
         //defaultAdapter = new MyAdapter(MainDIY.this, daftarData);
         //listview.setAdapter(defaultAdapter);
         defaultAdapter = new MyAdapter(DIY.this, nameList);*/



        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        listview.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));




        listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        hasilDataTersimpan();

        // float button
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainDIY.this, AddDIY.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        //List<DataDIY> contacts = db.getAllContact();

        // for (DataDIY cn : contacts) {
        //     String log = "Name: " + cn.getName() ;
        // Writing Contacts to log
        //   Log.d("Name: ", log);
        //}
        // Create the list of names which will be displayed on search
        //for (String id: nameList) {
        // mDbAdapter.createContact(DataDIY);}

    }

   // menampilkan apa yang dicari dan ada di database
   private void hasilPencarian(String query) {
        /**  */

        Cursor cursor = db.searchByInputText((query != null ? query : "@@@@"));



        String[] from = new String[]
                {
                        DBAdapter.COL_NAME
                };
        int[] to = new int[]
                {
                        R.id.txtName
                };Log.d("MainActivity","mencari dan memakai id list item");

        SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_adapter, cursor, from, to); // atu list
        Log.d("MainActivity","mencari dan memakai id list item");


        listview.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Cursor cur = db.getAllContact();



        //listview Click listener
        /** listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

         Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listview.getItemAtPosition(position);

         String selectedName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
         Toast.makeText(DIY.this, selectedName, 0).show();

         listview.setAdapter(defaultAdapter);

         for (int pos = 0; pos < nameList.size(); pos++) {
         if (nameList.get(pos).equals(selectedName)){
         position = pos;
         break;
         }
         }

         Handler handler = new Handler();
         final int finalPosition = position;
         handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        listview.setSelection(finalPosition);
        }
        });

         searchView.setQuery("",true);
         }
         }); */


    }


    // menampilkan data" yang tersimpan
    private void hasilDataTersimpan() {
        /** Load database setelah mengklik gambar tugu diy*/
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Cursor cur = db.getAllContact();

        String[] from = new String[]
                {
                        DBAdapter.COL_NAME
                };
        int[] to = new int[]
                {
                        R.id.txtName
                };

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_adapter, cur, from, to);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        // Inflate menu to add items to action bar if it is present.
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                if (!newText.isEmpty()){
                    hasilPencarian(newText + "*");
                    Timber.i("text berubah "+newText.toString());
                } else {
                    hasilDataTersimpan();

                    Timber.i("searchview kosong");
                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                hasilPencarian(query + "*");

                Log.d("MainActivity", "mencari di onQueryTextSubmit " + query.toString());
                return false;
            }
        };
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListener);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }




    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int pos, long id)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putLong(KEY_ID, id);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainDIY.this, EditDIY.class);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        db.close();
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onClose() {
        Timber.d("onclose");

        return false;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        hasilPencarian(query + "*");

        Log.d("MainActivity", "mencari di onQueryTextSubmit " + query.toString());
        return false;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if (!newText.isEmpty()){
            hasilPencarian(newText + "*");
            Timber.i("text berubah "+newText.toString());
        } else {
            hasilDataTersimpan();

            Timber.i("searchview kosong");
        }

        return false;
    }

    /** public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
     if (!newText.isEmpty()){
     hasilPencarian(newText + "*");
     Timber.d("onquerytextchange = "+ newText.toString());
     } else {
     myList.setAdapter(defaultAdapter);
     }

     return false;
     } */

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (db  != null) {
            db.close();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            //use the query to search
        }
    }


}
```

DataDIY.java

```
public class DataDIY
{
    private int     id;
    private String  name;
    private String  telp;
    private String kata;

    public DataDIY()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public DataDIY(String name, String telp, String kata)
    {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.telp = telp;
        this.kata = kata;
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getTelp()
    {
        return telp;
    }

    public void setTelp(String telp)
    {
        this.telp = telp;
    }

    public String getKata()
    {
        return kata;
    }

    public void setKata(String kata)
    {
        this.kata = kata;
    }

}
```

DBAdapter.java

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DBAdapter
{
    private static final String DB_NAME     = "contact_db";
    private static final int    DB_VER      = 1;

    public static final String  FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE   = "contact";
    public static final String  COL_ID      = "_id";
    public static final String  COL_NAME    = "name";
    public static final String  COL_TELP    = "telp";

    private static final String TAG         = "ContactDBAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper      dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase      db;

    private static final String DB_CREATE   = "create virtual table " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE+
        " using fts3 (_id integer primary key, name text not null);";

    private final Context       context;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VER);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL(DB_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(TAG, "upgrade DB");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);

        }

    }

    public DBAdapter(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException
    {
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close()
    {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    public void createContact(DataDIY contact)
    {
        ContentValues val = new ContentValues();
        val.put(COL_NAME, contact.getName());
        //val.put(COL_TELP, contact.getTelp());
        db.insert(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null, val);
    }

    public boolean deleteContact(int id)
    {
        return db.delete(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, COL_ID + "=" + id, null) > 0;
    }

    public Cursor getAllContact()
    {
        return db.query(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, new String[]
                {
                        COL_ID, COL_NAME
                }, null, null, null, null, null);
    }


    public Cursor getSingleContact(int id)
    {
        Cursor cursor = db.query(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, new String[]
                {
                        COL_ID, COL_NAME
                }, COL_ID + "=" + id, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        return cursor;
    }

    public boolean updateContact(DataDIY contact)
    {
        ContentValues val = new ContentValues();
        val.put(COL_NAME, contact.getName());
        //val.put(COL_TELP, contact.getTelp());

        return db.update(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, val, COL_ID + "=" + contact.getId(), null) > 0;
    }

    public Cursor searchByInputText(String inputText) throws SQLException {

        String query = "SELECT *"
                 +  " from " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE +
                " where " + COL_NAME + " = '" + inputText+"'"  ;

        Log.d("DBAdapter","mencari di searchbyinputtext " + query.toString());

        Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();


        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }

        Log.d("DBAdapter","melewati mCursor rawquery");
        return mCursor;

    }

}
```

Tell me if my method is wrong. 
Here another [java in git](https://github.com/buruhnih/CRUD-and-Search-Android-Sqlite-Database-Local/tree/master/app/src/main/java/inklinked/tessearchtambahfitur)

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall and then again install the app in your device.
because many times updation in sqlite database is only affect when application is installed 1st time in device.
Hope it works.

Comment: still give "Empty Data" for me

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL query, you are looking for an exact match, but seems like you want results containing what you typed.
Try with the clause `LIKE` instead of `=` :

```
public Cursor searchByInputText(String inputText) throws SQLException {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM "+ FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE +
            " WHERE" + COL_NAME + " LIKE '%" + inputText + "%'";
```

I used the wildcard `%` at both ends, but you could also use `_`, or nothing, depending on what you are looking. See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html for more details.

Comment: ok, no error, but the method hasilPencarian(...) not works(not make a display or still "empty data" but no error ..

Answer (score 0):

It can display.. its work.. 
For you newbie want learning CRUD and Search SQLite Local Database, have a look into [my github](https://github.com/buruhnih/Android-SQLite-Local-Database-CRUD-Search/tree/master/app/src/main/java/inklinked/tessearchtambahfitur)

Thanks v u answer bfr